# Is there any way to enable keyboards to copy from host machine (Mac OS) to VM (Mac OS) set up in UTM?

Tags: copy-paste, virtualization

The [documentation](https://docs.getutm.app/guest-support/sharing/clipboard/#enabling-clipboard-sharing) says no support, but is there a work around with some other tools?

"MACOS 13+ Clipboard sharing is now supported for Linux guests running on the Apple backend. There is still no support for macOS guests."

For example I've done this successfully with Ubuntu, [via spice-vdagent](https://docs.getutm.app/settings-apple/virtualization/#macos-13-clipboard-sharing) but can't seem to do it with Mac OS. Is there an equivalent?